# Why do I keep getting '429 Too Many Requests' for put requests to add members to a list on Twitter's API?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, http-status-code-429

I am using the following Tweepy code to access the Twitter API endpoint https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/members/create.json

It seems that I cannot add more than about 80 members in a given day, but the rate limit is stated to be 75 / 15 minutes. I have my requests throttled to be 50 members every 1000 seconds (16.7 minutes).

Code:

```
members_to_add = groups['ct']
list_id = '1520581139982868483'
for member in members_to_add[1:2]:
    client.add_list_member(id=list_id, user_id=member)
    print(member)
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Is there another limit I am hitting that I don't know about?

Comment: This seems like the only official docs on their Standard v1.1 rate limits, unfortunately that endpoint isn't explicitly listed. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rate-limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is unfortunately an undocumented rate limit for this endpoint.

You can read more about it [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/undocumented-twitter-list-rate-limits/167531/33) (Twitter community forum).

But the main points of the Twitter official answer is that they will not provide any information about that limit and that there is nothing that we can do about it.

Comment: unbelievable!!   why have 5000 lists limit if they cannot be populated by code?  Hopefully Elon fixes this...

Comment: @woof_blitzer Yes, I don't understand neither but I'm sure that they have a really good reason to do that, as strange as it may seem. Anyway, can you please consider marking this question as solved if you think that this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just testing your code and need a quick fix, try cleaning your browsing history and deleting the cookies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That wont work because it's not cookie based, it is bearer token and key based. Clearing your browser will never make a difference.